# How to show only the last two digits of a number in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet like this in LibreOffice Calc:

```
     1         2
A    012345678 Henry 
B    012345679 George
```

The first column displays some ID numbers.

I need to display a shorter form of this number in another column, showing only the last two digits. This would look like this:

```
     3
A    78
B    79
```

How can I show only the last two digits of a number in LibreOffice Calc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cell `A2` contains `012345678`, then to get `78` to display in cell D2, enter `=right(A2, 2)` in cell D2.